# How to replace two words with blank space in a comma-separated String using regex in Java?

Tags: java, regex, string, replaceall

I have the following String

```
""00001","Open","2020-10-23 12:45","2022-10-20 15:48","Error not found","Alex Smith","NO ERROR","ErrorApp","FOB","CNSHA","GB","Plane","MODEL","2020-10-24 00:00","New","1","","2022-10-20 15:48""
```

I need to replace the 4th and the last words (dates) with an empty String "".

I have tried several regex expressions but couldn't get them to work.

The result should be:

```
    ""00001","Open","2020-10-23 12:45","","Error not found","Alex Smith","NO ERROR","ErrorApp","FOB","CNSHA","GB","Plane","MODEL","2020-10-24 00:00","New","1","","""
```

This regex:

```
actualLines[1].replaceAll("^(\".+?\",\".+?\",\".+?\",\")([0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2} [0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2})(.*)$", "$1$3}");
```

It replaces the 4th, but I need both 4th and the last element to be replaced.

Does anyone know how this can be done? Thanks

Comment: See [this quick try](https://regex101.com/r/Jtq8ry/1), maybe it helps (not much time at the moment).

Comment: Thanks, I've tried and it doesn't work for some reason. I'm using the replaceAll method.

Comment: [Java demo @tio.run](https://tio.run/##dVJbT8IwFH7nV5wsPGwqSzcxMSPEoKI@KDPskWFSR4Fi1zVd5yXIb8euK1FRTpN@p1/PrT1nhV9xZzV72W5pLgqpYKUJv1KU@ZIsyLv/gFW2JLLXOnD/iJUikvdaGcNlCcN3nAtGYN0CLaJ6ZjSDUmGl4bWgM8gx5W6iJOWLyRSwXJSeNa5lTjlm0FyDSQB9cJ7cNE0d9yKqYfJU79Ojej/x1qcbb5/93CeMu9d2ev/nKRvQiVK9kJZAh06dWBBulBCFqBOgTngKQRh1z3ZkaEgEwVnUPTfkUMpCAi8UzIuKzww3YPoVSU7V0hxHMQzH43j8bT8Qwhxu4kuDV6PkbmC024Z4ZJgToz3E18P73zV1AaEIoSY2eTPY1H@gTL34wa@onktV/0Q7qA3b4R9D228QFvs7xs@KXFBGXNM2b9/PzpHuf4P9XQTfMm7TBq93aBjKitWlWXM9foLhjAwYc03VPxyTj1KR3C8q5QvtrBh3naS2oUpPbsFtsAgcOLa69d60NtvtFw) from regex101 code generator.

Comment: No idea why generator put `\\\"` [works with `\"` too](https://tio.run/##dVJNT8MwDL3vV1jRDi2wKi1DQp0mNGDAAShaj@uQQhdGRppGacqHYL99pGmm8TXnYPvl@cWKvSQvpLecP6/XrJCl0rA0QFBrxgNFF/QtuCE6f6Jq0Nlxf0e0pkoMOjknVQXjN1JITuGjA8Zk/cBZDpUm2riXks2hIEx4qVZMLKYzIGpR@Y7c2CMThEN7DfYBGAK69zLkncQZmt5naLaXoQP/43Dlb/PPbWiofhcN/lesWmckM3OwsdCIZSiRVNggwhHuhbgXHUIYxf2jDRhZEEN4FPePLThWqlQgSg2PZS3mFhtx029aMP1k09sExpNJMtnyR1La5CI5tf7sNr0a2eiyBe44EdRGN8n5@PpnT33AOMa41aav1rf972jTHLHzK@qHSjc/0Q0bYjf6Q3STBen8cIMEeVlIxqlnB@T/rnMbYybd@uFGIXCI147BH@wae1XzpjVHN4smOcnpiHPPdv2tMH2vNC2CstaBNMWaCw@lDYdps6OlcGIxINh3satedVbr9Rc) :)

Comment: Hmm, surprisingly but it's not working. See here: https://freeimage.host/i/tiggQn.
While the regex I posted above works, it removes only the 4. element, and not the last one too.

Comment: Weird, hope you find why it's not working. I can't see the reason at first glance. Maybe because of the first and last doublequote, last [try this one](https://regex101.com/r/Jtq8ry/2) (also subst changed to `$1\"\"`)

Comment: Well, @bobblebubble, you just made my day! This is working, thank you!

Comment: Welcome @AleksandarGrujic so I put an answer for you :) Glad we got it to work!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An idea to use an [alternation](https://www.regular-expressions.info/alternation.html) for matching both, the fourth and last double-quoted part:

```
^((?:\"[^\"]*\",){3})\"[^\"]*\"|\"[^\"]*\"$
```

See [this demo at regex101](https://regex101.com/r/Jtq8ry/2) or a [Java demo at tio.run](https://tio.run/##dVJNT8MwDL3vV1gRhxZYlZZNQp0mNGDAAShajytIoQsjI02jNIUh2G8faZppfM2XZ7/YL5btBXkl3cXsZb1mhSyVhoUhglozHig6p8vghuj8mapBZ8f7HdGaKjHo5JxUFYyXpJCcwkcHjMn6kbMcKk20gdeSzaAgTHipVkzMp/dA1LzyXXJjT0wQDu0z2A9gCOjB807iDE0fMnS/n6FD/@No5W/jz627hwb/a1UtGLEMYWOhkclQIqmwToQj3A1xNzqCMIp7/Q0ZWRJD2I97x5YcK1UqEKWGp7IWM8uNuOkzLZh@tuFtAuPJJJls80dS2uAiObV4dptejax32RJ3nAhqvZvkfHz9s6ceYBxj3GrTN4tt/zva3DmE@rHSzQz2wqb2T5rbJUiHww0T5GUhGaeeXYn/u87diNlti8ONQuAYrx2/P9i16KrmTWMu3ZyW5CSnI8492/O3wvS90rQIyloH0hRrLjyUNjlMm6sshROLAcGB8131qrNar78A)

Replace with `$1\"\"` where `$1` is a [reference](https://www.regular-expressions.info/replacebackref.html) to what's captured by the *first* [group](https://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html). It holds the first three comma separated quoted parts `(?:"[^"]*",){3}` where `[^"]` matches [characters other than](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html#negated) quotes. On the right side of the alternation the part at the `$` [end](https://www.regular-expressions.info/anchors.html) gets matched (and `$1` is empty).

Comment: Hi, me again. May I ask if you can help me one more time? It's because I need to shift the last element 3 spaces to the left. So now it's no longer the last element, but I still need to replace it with "". I have now 21 elements, and it is on the 18.

Comment: Ok, thanks. I've created a new question. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74154861/how-to-replace-two-elements-in-a-java-string-using-regex

Comment: @AleksandarGrujic I see your new question got closed (just remove it if you like). I understand now just the position of the previous last has changed and everything else seems to be same. Try to search for [this pattern and replace with `$1\"\"$2`](https://regex101.com/r/mxDP1r/2)